# How to distinguish the mode (Java/JS/Android) the Processing sketch runs?

Tags: java, javascript, android, processing, mode

I write a multiplatform logic game, that will have to work in all modes: Java, JS and Android. I need to do some things different in all modes (especially, but not limited to, storage, for Java/Android I want to use load/saveTable and for JS - localStorage).

To do that I need to get the information, which is the mode the sketch runs. And I need to do this in runtime, just to avoid keeping different source for all platforms.

I was looking in the docs but found nothing in the topic. My Google research also led me to thoughts, that nobody even asked for that...

I was thinking about using try/catch to check some functions that exist in Java but not in JS, but this seems to be rather unelegant and whatismore I can not find the propper way for that.

What I have found is:

```
try {
  PApplet a;
  a = new PApplet();
  mode = "JAVA";
}
catch(Throwable e) {
  mode = "JS";
}
```

This distinguishes Java and JavaScript, but can not recognize Android...

So to summarize - what's the best way to distinguish, whether I run the sketch in JS or Java mode on runtime?

Comment: Java is a compiled language while JavaScript is an interpreted. That means that despite you just pressing a Play button, in Java mode your source code is compiled to java bytecode and you are left with a compiled binary program which you "can't" further change, while in JavaScript your source code is converted to JavaScript source code and what you are left with is just the converted readable source in a file. Thus, the decision is made at **compile time** and you will always need the Processing IDE to recompile everything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand, that the source will be compilled for Android app, Java executable and JS separatelly. But I just like to write the code, that will have the same source for all the platforms, thus I will only have to compile them without further changes for each platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found quite nice way with try/catch:

```
String mode;

mode = "unknown";

try {
  java.lang.Object a;
  a = new java.lang.Object();
  mode = "JAVA";
}
  catch(Throwable e) {
  mode = "JS";
}
```

This distinguishes JavaScript from the Java/Android but can not distinguish Android from Java. But since the differences are minimal this not causes significant problems with compatibility to me.

If someone knows the way to do this better - please post your answer!

Comment: I'm guessing you can also do something similar and try to instantiate an Android specific class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to detect Java vs. Android mode. Kind-of a hack:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

Method getInternalProcessingMethod(String methodName) {
    /*
     * Helper method that can be used to return
     * an internal processing method by name
     */
    Class cls = this.getClass();
    
    try {
        return cls.getMethod(methodName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

boolean isAndroidMode() {
    /*
     * Determine if we're running in Android mode or not
     */
     
    // What?
    // In Android mode 'displayDensity' is a field and in Java
    // mode 'displayDensity' is a method. This is a hack...but
    // it works.
    if (getInternalProcessingMethod("displayDensity") == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then you can use this to do something like what I use it for:

```
void settings() {
    IS_ANDROID_MODE = isAndroidMode();
    if (IS_ANDROID_MODE) {
        println("Android mode detected");
        fullScreen();
        SAVE_LOCATION = "blah.json";
    } else {
        println("Java mode detected");
        size(600, 1233);
        SAVE_LOCATION = "data/blah.json";
    }
}
```

Now I can have my test app run on my desktop in a small window but then run fullscreen with a different save file path on Android.